# How to get value from List<String>

Tags: android

We get data from server like this:

```
type=async-response
     &serial-number=00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000077fb51
     &merchant-order-id=902B4FF5
     &paynet-order-id=208832
     &end-point-id=823
```

We store it like that

```
List<String> elephantList = Arrays.asList(text.split("&"));
```

How could i get particular value against particular key ?

Comment: we store server data as String variable "text"

Comment: use `elephantList.get(index);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), Use [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to store key-value pair.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(response,"&");  
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {  
    String[] value = st.nextToken().split("=");
    map.put(value[0], value[1]);
    System.out.println("Key is:"+value[0]);  
    System.out.println("Value is:"+value[1]);  
}
```

To get value against key:

```
String serialNumber = map.get("serial-number");
```